# Making an Object disappear after a CCActionSequence

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I'm making an iOS game and part of it includes a marble that is randomly spawned and moves along a path and disappears upon completion of said path. Here is what I am using to spawn and move the marble:

```
-(void) createMarbleObstacle :(CCTime) randomTimeInterval{
    marbleObj = (Marble *)[CCBReader load: @"Marble"];
    marbleObj.position= _cLnode.position;
    [_contentNode addChild: marbleObj];
    [marbleObj moveMarble:(randomTimeInterval*5) :_bLnode: _aLnode];
}

-(void) moveMarble: (CCTime)interval :(CCNode*)a :(CCNode*)b{
    moveM1 = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:(interval) position: a.position];
    moveM2 = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:(interval) position: b.position];

    moveM4 = [CCActionSequence actions:moveM1, moveM2, nil];

    [self runAction: moveM4];
}
```

However, I can't figure out how I would go about making the marble disappear upon completion of the `CCActionSequence`. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add yet another action to your sequence in `moveMarble`:

```
id clean = [CCActionCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
   [_contentNode removeChild:marbleObj cleanup:YES];
}];
 moveM4 = [CCActionSequence actions:moveM1, moveM2, clean, nil];
```

or something like that :)